# java. Method return Null. What exception I must generated?

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception

I have this line code:

```
String name = Book.getName();

/*next lines of code*/
```

Next, variable `name` processing in other code without any checks.
In some cases, possible situation, when `name=null` and other code will exit with an error.

It is bad.

Also, I cant access to the other code.

**So, what do you think, my next implementation is correct**:

```
    try
    {
    String name = Book.getName();
    if(null== name)

    throw new NullPointerException("method 'getName' return null");

/*next lines of code*/
    }

    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
    System.out.print("Hey! Where book name? I exit!");
    System.exit();
    }
```

**I have any other choose in this case?**

It is possible to generate any other type of `Exception` or only `NullPointerException`?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Ok,

```
  String name = Book.getName();
```

it's imagine code line. In real case, I have more complex code:

```
List<Book> bookList= new ArrayList<Book>();
String name = null;

Iterator i = BookShop.getBooks.iterator(); //BookShop it is input parameter!

while(i.hasNext())
{

Book book = (Book) i.next;
name = book.getName();

nameList.add(name);


}
```

This example more full.

So, in this code input parameter `BookShop` Object.

What problem I can have with this Object?

1. BookShop can be `NULL`;
2. method `BookShop.getBooks()` can return `NULL`;

Also, `getName()` can return `NULL` too.

So, general problem next: **there is no guarantee the correctness of input parameter BookShop!**

And I must to consider every possible option (3 `NULL`)

For me, add General `try-catch` block and that all.

No?

Comment: +1 for "Hey! Where book name? I exit!"

Comment: Perhaps the best technique would be not to have the methods return null. Why would a book shop have null books instead of no (an empty set of) books? Then you can happily implicitly NPE if a null is ever returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use `IllegalStateException`:

```
 String name = Book.getName();
 if (name == null) {
     throw new IllegalStateException
         ("Method foo must not be called when the book has no name");
 }
```

It really depends on where the state is coming from though - it's not really clear what's going wrong here.

I certainly *wouldn't* start catching `NullPointerException` - exceptions like that (and the illegal state one) shouldn't be explicitly caught. Let them bubble up, and if it's appropriate have some sort of top-level handler.

Comment: @user471011: It's still not clear under what situation there won't be a book. Does this depend on user input? Does it represent some error in the system? Should the program definitely exit?

Comment: ,Yes, System can contains some errors. It not surprise for me :(

Comment: @user471011: But *is* it an error? Or is it just naturally missing data, e.g. because you've asked for a book which doesn't exist? You need to determine whether this is *really* an error, and how you want to handle it.

Comment: my code is service code, First Level code send for me some data, I process this data (getName) and send results (name) to other code block. If something wrong with input data - I must stop work and write log - that all. And what mean wrong data in my situation? If some info - null. It is general problem. also, possible situation with ClassCastException. And i must processing all this variants.

Comment: It sounds like you *should* be throwing an exception in this case, although `ClassCastException` doesn't sound appropriate either. If you can't complete your method's purpose correctly, then throwing an exception is appropriate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8317/discussion-between-user471011-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @user471011: No, chat doesn't work for my work patterns I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You can create any exception you like by extending the [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) class, like a `NoNameProvidedException` for example. There are a lot of example one Google to help you do that.

I guess in your case just checking with an `if` if the `name` is `null` should be sufficient as you just want to do a `System.exit()`.

Comment: +1 While the OP explicitly asked if it's possible to generate any other type of exception, you are correct that it's inappropriate in this case just to exit the process.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit iffy, but I assume you're learning. You don't need to throw the NullPointerException explicitly, you can throw whatever Exceptions you like.
But you probably don't really need the Exception catching here, you can just check for the `null` and handle the situation appropriately if it's true.

Also, please avoid `Yoda conditions`. Your `if` statement should read

`if name is null`

so

`if (name == null)`

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should not be used for normal control flow. Just use the `if` block:

```
String name = Book.getName();
if (name == null) {
    System.out.print("Hey! Where book name? I exit!");
    System.exit();
}

/*next lines of code*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using try and catch in this case is unneeded. You can just write like this:

```
if(Book.getName() != null)
   String name = Book.getName();
else
   //handle the situation with null
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to throw an Exception in this case - just handle the `null` value and you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's more friendly for Java not to use exceptions, but just check the return value

```
String name = Book.getName();
if (name == null)
    System.out.print("Hey! Where book name? I exit!");
else {
    /*next lines of code*/
}
```